# What is preferred composition or aggregation in UML?

Tags: c++, oop, aggregation, composition

I am synthesizing all the UML patterns -

Like Adaptor Pattern, Commander Pattern, Wrapper Pattern.

My question is what is preferred composition or aggregation. Also, why is it preferred so ?

Comment: Aggregation is preferred, because aggregation means low couple。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to prefer some of kind of association. Both, composition or aggregation are used in specific situations in model. I recommend you to read UML Specification. Find info about association end, association and property element. [Here is UML web site](http://www.uml.org)